# Show that $P[A∩B]P[A∪B]≤P[A]P[B]$ for all events $A, B$.

Tags: probability

My question is about probability.

Show that $P[A∩B]P[A∪B]≤P[A]P[B]$ for all events $A, B$.

Solution attempt:
$P[A]≤P[A∪B]$

and

$P[B]≤P[A∪B]$

$P[B]P[A]≤P[A∪B]$ 
(because $P[A]≤1$)

Comment: Am I supposed to do it as my homework?

Comment: @mhbrhm I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @Jakobian no but are you really interested in seeing my thoughts? Although now I get why you have this rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a:=P[A],\,b:=p[B],\,c:=P[A\cap B]$ so $P[A\cup B]=a+b-c$. You want to prove $ac+bc-c^2\le ab$, or equivalently $(a-c)(b-c)\ge0$. But $a-c,\,b-c$ are obviously $\ge0$; they're respectively $P[A\setminus B],\,P[B\setminus A]$.

Answer (score 2):

It's $$P(A\cap B)(P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B))\leq P(A)P(B)$$ or
$$(P(A)-P(A\cap B))(P(B)-P(A\cap B))\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Have a look at the values taken by $xy$ under condition $x+y=c$ where $c$ is some constant.

Further note that $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$.